# Bulma: Place Image and Text Side by Side in Container

Tags: html, css, bulma

I just started working with Bulma CSS Framework. However, I am unable to place text and background image side by side. The background image gets cut. Please help me.

Image I want to add: [image]

Here's the Code:

```
<section class="hero is-halfheight upload-descr" style = "height: 37em">
    <div class="hero-body">     
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr class = "rm-descr-bar" style = "float: left;"></hr>
            <div class="clearfix" style = "clear:both;"></div>
            <h1 class = "title">
                Loren Ipsum
            </h1>
            <div class="content rm-has-medium-size">
                <p class = "upload-descr-exp" aria-live = "polite" aria-atomic = "true">Sounds traditional, right? Loren Ipsum Does<br />Loren ipsum dolar sit amet. Loren Ipsum<br />Loren Ipsum dolar sit amet. Loren ipsum dolar sit amet.<br />Loren Ipsum dolar sit amet.<br />Loren Ipsum dolar sit amet is cool</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want to place the image just side to the `.upload-descr-exp` description. But it just gets cut.

I tried:

```
<section class="hero is-halfheight upload-descr" style = "height: 37em">
    <div class="hero-body">     
        <div class="container" style = "background: url('/img/cover.jpg') no-repeat right">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr class = "rm-descr-bar" style = "float: left;"></hr>
            <div class="clearfix" style = "clear:both;"></div>
            <h1 class = "title">
                Loren Ipsum
            </h1>
            <div class="content rm-has-medium-size">
                <p class = "upload-descr-exp" aria-live = "polite" aria-atomic = "true">Sounds traditional, right? Loren Ipsum Does<br />Loren ipsum dolar sit amet. Loren Ipsum<br />Loren Ipsum dolar sit amet. Loren ipsum dolar sit amet.<br />Loren Ipsum dolar sit amet.<br />Loren Ipsum dolar sit amet is cool</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you add a picture or diagram of the outcome you want? Thanks

Comment: Please see the edit @sol

Comment: You want the image on the right?

Comment: Yes @sol. Please do it.